# Difference between creating an object using new keyword and using clone method

Tags: java

What is the difference between creating an object using the `new` keyword and creating an object using [`clone()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29)? Is there any difference between memory allocation?

Answer (score 5):

`new` creates an object according to the constructor, while `clone()` creates a new object and initializes the fields with the contents of the original object.

I take it, you read the javadoc, so let me take you through an example:

```
public class MyBaby implements Cloneable {

    int age = 0;
    String name = "Dolly";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyBaby originalBaby = new MyBaby();
        originalBaby.setAge(1);
        try {
            // We clone the baby.
            MyBaby clonedBaby = (MyBaby) originalBaby.clone();
            // both babies now have: age 1, name "Molly" and an empty arraylist
            originalBaby.setAge(2);
            // originalBaby has age 2, the clone has age 1
            originalBaby.setName("Molly");
            // same goes for the String, both are individual fields
            originalBaby.getList().add("addedString");
            // both babies get the string added to the list, 
            // because both point to the same list.
            System.out.println(clonedBaby.toString());
        }
        catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {}
    }
}
```

The javadoc says:

> this method performs a "shallow copy" of this object, not a "deep
>   copy" operation.

which explains the behaviour of our babies' list: References are copied, not the elements that are referenced, thus our copy is "shallow"

The memory allocation can differ of course:

1. you can initialize fields in your constructor
2. clone can initialize a field, i.e. an array

Answer (score 3):

`new` operator instantiates the new object while `clone()` is more like a **copy constructor**. `clone()` method creates **a copy of the object with values of member attributes also copied**.

Answer (score 1):

Simple stated,

> new creates an instance

while

> clone returns a clone of an instance.

Answer (score 1):

**Clone()** creates a new instance of the same class and copies all the fields to the new instance and returns it (shallow copying).

while the **new** keyword is a Java operator that creates the object ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html ).

Answer (score 0):

- new() construcion of object as per default constructor.
- clone() does shallow copy of references.

We should use clone only when the cost of object creation is high and we would rather clone and set the behaviour.